# Regex : exclude specific path in a global research

Tags: regex

I created a regex that detects specific extensions within a windows path (and that are not executed from C:)

Example : "c:\test1\test.exe" does not match

"D:\test1\test.exe" match

Here is the regex in question

```
.*"[a-bd-zA-BD-Z]:[\\\/](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\\/])*([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(exe|bat|vbs))".*
```

On the other hand, I would like to modify the regex to say, if the path is "E:\temp\exe.exe" then you don't match

How is it possible to create an exception?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent matching the extension before the last character class using a negative lookahead:

```
"[a-bd-zA-BD-Z]:[\\\/](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\\/])*(?!(?:exe|bat|vbs)\.)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(exe|bat|vbs))"
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bx4ubD/1).

Or if a lookbehind is supported, exclude what should not be directly to the left before the dot:

```
"[a-bd-zA-BD-Z]:[\\\/](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\\/])*([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?<!\bexe)\.(exe|bat|vbs))"
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J4Ri2W/1).